# How do I make a calc with logs information under?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have build calc and I wanted to add a logs for calculator but my script is not working. Someone see
where is mistake? I am learning for a few days and decided to make a project but after many hours of looking at code, browsing everything in internet I decided to ask you. I know there are probably many easier projects for a beginner, but I don't want to abandon a project before finishing.
Here is js script.

```js
funtion changeContent() {
  var x = document.getElementById('textarea');
  var liczba11 = document.getElementById('liczba1');
  var liczbaa2 = document.getElementById('liczba2');

  x.value = x.value + liczba11.value + liczbaa2.value + '\r\n';
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Sumowanie dwóch liczb - wprowadź dane</legend>
    <p>Liczba1 <input type="text" name="liczba1" id="liczba1" /></p>
    <p>Liczba2 <input type="text" name="liczba2" id="liczba2" /></p>
    <p>Wynik : <input type="text" name="wynik" readonly="readonly" /></p>
    <button
      onclick="this.form.elements['wynik'].value = parseFloat(this.form.elements['liczba1'].value) + parseFloat(this.form.elements['liczba2'].value); return false"
    >
      Oblicz
    </button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<form action="">
  <div>
    <textarea
      name="uwagi"
      id="textarea"
      cols="30"
      rows="3"
      value="text"
      disabled="disabled"
    ></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
<button onclick="changeContent()">Click to change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the onclick handler to hold the code, you can run a function from it.

You also misspelled `function`.

I added the logging code to the runCalc function so that it all happens at the same time, no extra button needed.

```js
function runCalc(){
  liczba11 = document.getElementById('liczba1');
  liczbaa2 = document.getElementById('liczba2');
  wynik = document.getElementById('wynik');
  logs = document.getElementById('textarea');
  wynik.value = parseFloat(liczba11.value) + parseFloat(liczbaa2.value);
  logs.value += parseFloat(liczba11.value) + " + " + parseFloat(liczbaa2.value) + " = " + wynik.value + "\r\n";
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Sumowanie dwóch liczb - wprowadź dane</legend>
    <p>Liczba1 <input type="text" name="liczba1" id="liczba1" /></p>
    <p>Liczba2 <input type="text" name="liczba2" id="liczba2" /></p>
    <p>Wynik : <input type="text" name="wynik" id="wynik" readonly="readonly" /></p>
    <button type="button"
      onclick="runCalc()"
    >
      Oblicz
    </button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<form action="">
  <div>
    <textarea
      name="uwagi"
      id="textarea"
      cols="30"
      rows="3"
      value="text"
      disabled="disabled"
    ></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to implement, calculation in programming language. There's so mutch anything to handle, priority, divizion by zero. With the power of programming language there's [`eval` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) in javascript it can be easy to do.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
const str = document.querySelector('#liczba1')
const result = document.querySelector('#r')
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  if ( /^[0-9\*\/\-\+\(\)]+$/.test(str.value))
  {
    result.innerText = eval(str.value) // Be awaire of using eval function
    console.log(eval(str.value))
  } else
    result.innerText = 'Error, type missmatch'
})
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>String of calculation</legend>
  <p>Example: 3+4 OR 4*3 OR some complicate 7895*265+(423-(4/65+3))</p>
  <p><input type="text" name="liczba1" id="liczba1"/></p>
  <p>Result <strong id="r"></strong> </p>
  <button>
    Result
  </button>
</fieldset>
```

**IMPORTANT**
Check intentionnally using eval function.